# Get column of first occurence of a value in array

Tags: python, numpy

We have the following numpy array:

```
b = np.array([[0.3, -0.2, 0.4, 0.5, -0.8, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
             [0.6, 0.2, 0.7, 0.91, 0.67, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
             [0.5, 0.1, 0.7, 0.0, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
```

We can see here that in the right side of this array (last 3 columns) we have a diagonal matrix. How can I get the column where `1` first occur in this diagonal matrix? i.e., `column 5`. I tried the following, which gives the correct answer:

```
first_occurence = np.argmax(b == 1, axis=1)[0]
```

But, if we have the following array, this does not work, giving me `0` as answer (which should be `6`)

```
b = np.array([[0.3, -0.2, 0.4, 0.5, -0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.6, 0.2, 0.7, 0.91, 0.67, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
              [0.5, 0.1, 0.7, 0.0, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
```

Comment: For some reason, argmax seens to think a value in your first column is 1

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 yes, i have noticed that too. I'm confused.

Comment: It sees all zeros in the first row of `b == 1`, and from the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html): "In case of multiple occurrences of the maximum values, the indices corresponding to the first occurrence are returned."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```py
firsts = np.argmax(b == 1, axis=1)
first_occurence = min(firsts[firsts != 0])
```

The `firsts[firsts != 0]` argument to `min()` filters out rows for which `b` does not contain a `1`, and `min()` then finds the column you're looking for.

**UPDATE:**

Assumptions, based on OP's clarifications:

- the input contains a submatrix that is an identity matrix of order between `1` and `b.shape[0]` for input matrix `b`
- the rightmost column of this identity matrix is to be found within the rightmost column of the input matrix
- the top row of this identity matrix is between `0` and `b.shape[0] - 1`.

Here is a way to identify the column in the input matrix which contains the leftmost column in the embedded identity matrix:

```py
def foo(b):
    rows = b.shape[0]
    left = b.shape[1] - rows
    for tops in range(rows):
        order = rows - tops
        eye = np.eye(order)
        for top in range(tops + 1):
            if np.allclose(b[top:top + order, left:left + order], eye):
                return left
        left += 1
```

Test code:

```py
b1 = np.array([
         [0.3, -0.2, 0.4, 0.5, -0.8,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
         [0.6,  0.2, 0.7, 0.91, 0.67, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
         [0.5,  0.1, 0.7, 0.0,  0.6,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
b2 = np.array([
         [0.3, -0.2, 0.4, 0.5, -0.8,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
         [0.6,  0.2, 0.7, 0.91, 0.67, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
         [0.5,  0.1, 0.7, 0.0,  0.6,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
b3 = np.array([
         [0,   -0.2, 0.4, 0.5, -0.8,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
         [0.6, 1,    0.7, 0.91, 0.67, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
         [0.5, 0.1,  0.7, 0.0,  0.6,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
b4 = np.array([
         [0.3, -0.2, 0.4, 0.5, -0.8,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
         [0.6, 0.2,  0.7, 0.91, 0.67, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
         [0.5, 0.1,  0.7, 0.0,  0.6,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])

print( foo(b1) )
print( foo(b2) )
print( foo(b3) )
print( foo(b4) )
```

Output:

```
5
6
5
6
```

Comment: This is going to fail if we have the following array: `b = np.array([[0, -0.2, 0.4, 0.5, -0.8, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.6, 1, 0.7, 0.91, 0.67, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
              [0.5, 0.1, 0.7, 0.0, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])`

Comment: To clarify then, are you asking for logic that will detect the leftmost column of the largest identity matrix (i.e., diagonal with values of 1 on the diagonal) within `b`? It looks like you'll accept a diagonal matrix that goes all the way from top to bottom, as well as one that starts on the second row and goes all the way to the bottom. Would you also accept a diagonal matrix that starts on the top row and ends on the second row?

Comment: Yes, i guess that would be the correct question!

Comment: Please see my updated comment and confirm.

Comment: The updated code yields `1`. Yes, it can start and end in any row. Start in the first row and end in the second, or end in the third. It could also start in the second and end in the third , or even start in the third and end in the third. I posted a three row here for simplicity, but it can have `n` rows.

Comment: I guess the key constraint is that the diagonal matrix must *end* in the final column.

Comment: OK, please see my updated answer.